# Writing UI tests using Espresso for APK without source code

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am trying to write UI tests using Espresso for an APK but I don't have the source code. I am trying to init the `ActivityTestRule` using classpath.

I followed this [article](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Espresso+-+Write+tests+without+source+code+access)

```
  private static final String CLASSNAME = "com.mytaxi.android_demo.activities.AuthenticationActivity";
  private static Class<? extends Activity>  activityClass = (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(CLASSNAME);
  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<?> mActivityRule = newActivityTestRule(CLASSNAME);
```

but I caught this exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found"

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, this APK is proguard protected. So the classes/packages names are currently obfuscated. In another words, the names are currently different.

Try using [Monkey Runner](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner) instead